# How to set production environment variable in React app? (hosted on Netlify)

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables

I was wondering how I can set environment variable in React to hid my API key?

I am hosting the app on Netlify so I am not sure if that matters. I am able to successfully do it in development but when it gets to production, the api key becomes undefined.

In my .env file when I have:

```
REACT_APP_API_KEY="my_api_key_etc"
```

In my app.js I have:

```
const apiKey = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY
```

when I `console.log(apiKey)` in development (`npm start`): it shows my api fine, but when in production mode (npm run build): it shows undefined.

I have already tried to create two more files like `.env.development` and `.env.production` and still that didn't work.

Also I made sure my `.env` files are outside of my src folder.

Do you guys think it has something to do with Netlify?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can set it in the netlify dashboard...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should be setting these variables in your dashboard instead. Head to your Project settings, and add this, and any other variables under environment:

[image]